# Wasabi Wallet 2.0 stuck at "Waiting for Coinjoin"

Tags: coinjoin, wasabi-wallet

I have moved over to Wasabi Wallet 2.0. I'm trying to undertake my first CoinJoin (I have selected Max privacy)

I have a tick in the bottom right corner which shows Tor is running, backend connected and connected to 8+ peers.

After starting CoinJoin, the process does not move on from

"Waiting for CoinJoin"

This as been at this stage for over 12 hours. Unsure of the status or how to review what may be the problem?

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with the recent disruptions suffered by the Tor network.

Comment: It looks more like a bug or the user selected the economic profile which only coinjoins in the cheaper part of the week.

Answer (score 1):

That [message](https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/blob/a77c44c9ca28201fc6db7eb7e6db6728395f5f87/WalletWasabi.Fluent/ViewModels/Wallets/CoinJoinStateViewModel.cs#L236) AFAIK simply means that your wallet is waiting for coinjoin to happen, but if you didn't manage to participate in any coinjoin for 12 hours then something is wrong. Have you tried to restart Wasabi?

Make sure that you are using the latest version (2.0.1) which you can get here https://wasabiwallet.io/index.html#download

If the total sum of the non private coins is less than 0.01 BTC then you have to manually start participating in coinjoin by pressing the play button on the music box.

If none of the above helps check the logs and see if there is anything that explain what you are experiencing.